# Не могу понять что я упускаю

Tags: python

Только начал изучать python самостоятельно. Хочу отсортировать список от меньшего к большему.
Не могу понять что я упустил.

```
from random import randint
N = 10
arr = []
for i in range(N):
    arr.append(randint(1, 99))
print(arr)

a = 1
while arr[a:]:
    b = min(arr)
    arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]
    a += 1
print(arr)
```

Comment: так b у вас значение минимального элемента, а не его индекс.

Comment: И индекс надо начинать с нуля... Ну тут конечно интересная конструкция завершения цикла....

Comment: Причем прошу заметить, что если вы начнете искать индекс у минимального элемента, это проблему не решит, т.к. он не будет меняться, вам нужно будет действительно делать срез каждый раз, типа arr = arr[a:], только в самом условии while, а в условии завершения сделать просто while arr:

Comment: arr.index(elem) вернет индекс первого вхождения elem.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import randint
N = 10
arr = [randint(1, 99) for i in range(N)]

a = 0
while arr[a:]:
    b = arr.index(min(arr[a:]))
    arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]
    a += 1
    
print(arr)
```

Comment: Я чуть подправил генерацию списка, т.к. ваш вариант противоречит концепции Python'а.